# Is it possible to assign a new value to an array name?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, arguments

I read that;
Although an array name can be used as a pointer (after decaying into pointer), **it's not possible to assign it a new value**. Attempting to make it point elsewhere is an error:

```
while (*a != 0)  // a is of (int *) type  
    a++;         //wrong
```

On the other hand, when passed to a function, an array name is always treated as a pointer. The function call

```
largest = largest_num(b, n) // b is an array of int
```

for the function

```
int find_largest(int a[], int n)
{

   ....
   ....

}
```

causes **a pointer to the first element of `b` to be assigned to `a`**.
Above two statements ( in bold ) seems to me contradictory. I am confused.

Comment: `a` is pointer not array @`find_largest(int a[], int n)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Isn't `a[]` is local variable to `find_largest()`?

Comment: When you declare a function parameter as an array type, the compiler basically just says "screw you, this is a pointer".  And its identity as an array is entirely lost.  Huge wart on the language, in my opinion.

Comment: @haccks Yes, 'local variable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley; Then what is the need to declare an array parameter?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Then it must be treated as an array within its scope, isn't it?

Comment: @haccks: None. I never do it.  Even for `main`, some people, for some reason, prefer this signature: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` -- And I have no idea why.  It should be `int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Comment: @haccks no, as a pointer, in C function declarations and formal declarations are quite diffrent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a function declaration, an array is treated as if you'd declared a pointer, so

```
int find_largest(int a[], int n) {
```

is processed as if it were

```
int find_largest(int *a, int n) {
```

So `a` is a pointer, not an array, and there's no contradiction.

Since it's a pointer, you can reassign `a`, e.g.

```
a++;
```

is allowed.

Comment: It means that no space is allocated in the memory after declaring `int a[]`?

Comment: And that's exactly why it's treated this way.

Comment: Yes, space is allocated for the pointer, but not for the array. It just receives a pointer to the caller's array.

Comment: And then `a` is used as array name inside the function for further operation on array `b`, right?

Comment: No, it's used as a pointer inside the function. It is treated exactly as if you had declared it as a pointer, it's not an array.

Comment: It's actually the other way around. `a[i]` is a pointer expression, it's equivalent to `*(a+i)`. You can write `b[i]` because the array `b` decays to a pointer in this context. What this essentially means is that you can use `[]` with both arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

No contradiction there - you're still working with a pointer (to `int`), and `int a[]` notation is allowed only for convenience. Quoting [the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html):

> Since arrays decay immediately into pointers, an array is never
>   actually passed to a function. You can pretend that a function
>   receives an array as a parameter, and illustrate it by declaring the
>   corresponding parameter as an array:

```
void f(char a[])
```

> Interpreted literally, this declaration would have no use, so the
>   compiler turns around and pretends that you'd written a pointer
>   declaration, since that's what the function will in fact receive:

```
void f(char *a)
```

> This conversion of array-like declarators into pointers holds
>   only within function formal parameter declarations, nowhere else. If
>   the conversion bothers you, you're under no compulsion to make use of
>   it; many programmers have concluded that the confusion it causes
>   outweighs the small advantage of having the declaration ``look like''
>   the call or the uses within the function.